# Spring Boot + Hibernate - lazy initialization error on two levels of child hibernate objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I feel like this issue has been discussed before, but I can't find a solid answer.  I'm getting a `LazyInitializationException...no Session` when attempting to go two levels deep in accessing lazily-loaded hibernate objects.  I'm doing this through Spring Boot.

Suppose I have three Hibernate objects, `Table1`, `Table2` & `Table3`.  `Table1` has a one-to-many foreign-key reference to `Table2` & `Table2` has a one-to-many foreign-key reference to `Table3`.  Each foreign-key reference is `LAZY` loaded (I think this issue occurs with one-to-one relationships as well, but not 100% sure)

`Table1` has the following code:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "table1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Table2> table2s;

//and corresponding getter method
public Set<Table2> getTable2s(){
   return table2s
}
```

And the same pattern in the `Table2` class for referencing `Table3`.

I would expect that I can write the following code:

```
Table1 table1 = tableOneRepository.getOne(...);
Set<Table2> table2s = table1.getTable2s()
singleTable2 = table2s.iterator().next() // just get any one element, assume set in not empty
Set<Table3> table3s = singleTable2.getTable3s() // "no session" error
```

However, the final line always produces this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com...] - no Session
```

Note this issue never occurs when doing the first lazy load, **it's always when doing a lazy load from an object that was itself lazy loaded**

I've seen lots of suggestions about adding `@Transactional` to methods, but it hasn't worked.  Help please?

Comment: It seems weird. If you don't `join fetch` any of the associations, I would argue that `LazyInitializationException` should happen when you `getTable2s()`. Anyhow, I think you should create another method in `TableOneRepository` which will `join fetch` both associations, to avoid having multiple (or N+1) queries.

Answer (score 0):

Well we need more informations. First the declaration of the entities. Somehting might be missing. Then more code. Here we don't even have the declaration of the function

Even if it might not be the real cause, check you have imported the spring transactional annotation and not the javax annotation

Edit : as far as I remember I've also worked with "nested" objects like this.
Not sure, but might work : try to do this after you retrieved the singleTable2. I don't remember you have to do this when you access an object, but try it anyway

```
 Hibernate.initialize(singleTable2)
```

Comment: Valid comment about accidentally importing the `javax` annotation instead of the `spring` annotation.  I actually made that mistake and noticed it later.  Hopefully someone else will find this comment and save them some headache.

Comment: Was it the cause of your problem ?

Comment: No that wasn't actually the issue.  I'd noticed it before testing.  But still good info to leave here in case someone else makes that mistake.